# Number of occurrence of each element in less than n^2

Tags: java, algorithm, c++11

I'm given two arrays **a[n]**, **b[n]**, where n can be **10^5**

Initially **answer** array is of size **n** with all **zeroes**.

The task is to take **a[i]**, **b[i]** as interval for **answer[i]** and increment values between it by **1**.

Example:

```
         a[n] = {1,1,1,1,1};
         b[n] = {3,3,5,5,5};
```

so answer `[n] = {5, 5, 5, 3, 3}`

`b[i]` is always greater than `a[i]`

I have done this using bruteforce in n^2

```
int i=0;
int ans[n];
while(i<n){
  for(int j=a[i]; j<=b[i]; j++){
    ans[j]++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Is there any better way to solve this in ***linear time***.

Comment: Is ```b[i]``` always greater than ```a[i]``` and are both arrays always sorted? For example, you'll never have ```a=[1, 6, 3, 5]```?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Number of occurences of each term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57354722/number-of-occurences-of-each-term)

Comment: yes b[i] will be always greater than a[i]

Comment: @vivek_23 that's not quite what he's asking. @NitinSinghal will ```a``` be sorted and ```b``` sorted relative to ```a```?

Comment: @vivek_23 don't mark this question as a duplicate, kindly read the question carefully. I'm asking for a better way to solve this..i.e reduce time complexity

Comment: @NitinSinghal it's the same question. You have values in 2 different arrays. There, it has the values in a single array. What's the difference? The algorithm I mentioned there is also linear.

Comment: @vivek_23 oh really, can u let me know how this will work in linear time then?

Comment: @NitinSinghal The method is well visualized there. Note that you would just have a single extra auxiliary array to collect the `+1` and `-1` mentioned there. I am not creating a 2D matrix .

Comment: @vivek_23 can you write down the code, i'm not getting your point.

Comment: @vivek_23 your solution there says to go through intervals one by one, can u tell me how will this done in O(n) time. Remember i have two arrays a[n], b[n]

Comment: @NitinSinghal https://ideone.com/whI04p I have created an array of size `a.length+2` just for the sake of simplicity in computation.

Comment: Adding +1 takes O(1), subtracting 1 takes O(1). You do it for every interval, that is O(n) times. That takes O(n) time then. Finally you calculate prefix sums in O(n). In total: O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. Instead of performing increasing operation on whole range choose the starting index  of range to be increased and the last index+1 to be decreased.

Add the number at starting index and subtract the number from end_index + 1. If you observe carefully it is same.

At last find prefix subarray sum and that will be answer.

```
def increment(a,b,n):
    answer = [0]*(n+1)
    for i in range(n):
        lowerbound = a[i]
        upperbound = b[i]
        answer[lowerbound] += 1
        if upperbound < n:
            answer[upperbound+1] -= 1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        answer[i] += answer[i-1]
    answer = answer[1:]
    print(answer)
```